# Is there a proverb meaning that "one cannot give what one does not herself have"?

Tags: idiom-request, proverbs

Is there a proverb meaning that "one cannot give what one does not herself have"?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with "You can't give what you don't have."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't pour from an empty jug

(the context I usually see this phrase relates to giving too much of one's self and the implication being that you can't give any more love/attention/energy if you are low on those yourself.)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Your answer could be improved by providing references. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 7):

There is

[**You cannot get blood from a stone**](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/you-cant-get-blood-out-of-a-stone.html)

although that's a little more about avoiding futile activity.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of such proverb, but there's a [poem](https://hellopoetry.com/poem/15157/it-is-no-gift-i-tender/) by [Housman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._E._Housman) that says

> It is no gift I tender,
>           A loan is all I can;
>   But do not scorn the lender;
>           Man gets no more from man.